# How to select date from date picker using VBA selenium?

Tags: vba, selenium

I want to choose a date
if I select the 1st, then automatically click on the 1st

[image]

this is my code

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[contains(text(),'1')]").Click   ' not working

driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='btn-icon date-picker-month-date' and text()='1']").Click  ' not working
```

[image]

Comment: What does not working entail? Error messages?

Comment: Is there any editable text box linked to the date picker which fills with the selected dates?

Comment: which can be edited are hours and minutes